# Item Style XSL - Showing Read More Link When Content Is Cut Off

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I have managed to create an ItemStyle template for my CQWP. It pulls from various announcements. I have set the character limit to 400 and placed a link at the end where a user can click to view the full announcement. However, this displays on all announcements, regardless of length.

How can I set it to where the link *only* shows when the announcement is cut off / over 400 characters?

Here is my XSL:

```
                    <table> 
                    <tr><td>
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <h3><a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}"><xsl:value-of select="@MyTitle"/></a></h3>         
                    </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
                            <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring(@MyDesc,1,400)" /> - <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">[Full Announcement]</a><br /></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> 

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to show a "Show More" link when you only want to display, say, 3 items at time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to wrap that in an if, something along the lines of this:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@MyDesc) &gt; 400">
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring(@MyDesc,1,400)" /> - <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">[Full Announcement]</a><br />
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: That works! I had to put it before the start of the link or it would hide all the articles that were less than 400 characters.             
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="substring(@MyDesc,1,400)" /> <xsl:if test="string-length(@MyDesc) &gt; 400"> - <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}">[Full Announcement]</a><br />
</xsl:if>